# RSA decryption error - IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 128 bytes

Tags: java, key, rsa, jce

I am now on making RSA message authentication software. The process is as follows:

1. Sign the message by using A's private key (1024 bit)
2. Verify the message by using A's public key (1024 bit)

The #1 code (below) works fine and generates following result:

> 5554c9a9f6838b6cf40d9dbfbab3d90ea27aa6434ed095d289c13c2624617993ad99161ac265276d150510c176341d8ab8600d08b7353286d465e6bd3370a6fd8dd3ffb82916f612fd6dcee5e654ed801cfca6b6d2d5d6dc99ff7921b615abdf62eb67db1f71e6a6ea70012fd35e7cefa1a8d3aab7614c47746cfe1fc2bc875b

However the #2 code shows following error:

> `javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 128 bytes`

I think the line in #1 `Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");`
generates 2048 bits (256 bytes) result. Perhaps this is the problem... remember that I use 1024 bit private key.

So how can the #1 code generate 128-byte result?

**1. SignMail.java**

```
public class SignMail {

    static {
        Security.addProvider(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
    }

    public static String sign(String userOriginalMessage) throws Exception {

        PEMReader userPrivateKey = new PEMReader(
          new InputStreamReader(
             new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/pkcs10priv.key")));

        KeyPair keyPair = (KeyPair)userPrivateKey.readObject();

        byte[] cipherText;
        //modified by JEON 20130817
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        //encrypt the message using private key
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPrivate());
        cipherText = cipher.doFinal(userOriginalMessage.getBytes());
        return new String(Hex.encode(cipherText));

    }


}
```

**2. UserSMSVerifier.java**

```
public class UserSMSVerifier {

static String signedMail;

static {
    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
}


public static String messageGenarator(
        String UserCert,
        String origninalMessage         
        ) throws Exception{

    InputStream userCertStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(UserCert.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    PEMReader userCerti = new PEMReader(
              new InputStreamReader(
                      userCertStream));



    //KeyPair userPrivate = (KeyPair)userPrivateKey.readObject();
    X509Certificate userCert = (X509Certificate)userCerti.readObject();


    byte[] dectyptedText = null;
    // decrypt the text using the private key
    //modified by JEON 20130817
    //Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, userCert.getPublicKey());
    dectyptedText = cipher.doFinal(origninalMessage.getBytes());

    String result = new String(dectyptedText, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    return result;

}


}
```

the #2 code was executed by the following JSP

**#3 messageVeri.JSP**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=euc-kr" %>

<%@ page session = "true" %>

<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Statement" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.SQLException" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>

<%@ page import="myPackage.UserSMSVerifier" %>


<%
    request.setCharacterEncoding("euc-kr");

    String userID = request.getParameter("sender");
    String encryptedSMS = request.getParameter("encryptedSMS");

    //String sql = "select user_id, user_pw from testca.testca_init where user_id=? and user_pw=?";
    //String sql = "update testca.testca_init set pkcs10request = '"+pkcs10request_new+"' where user_id='user1'";
    String sql = "select * from testca.testca_init where user_id='" + userID + "'";

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String jdbcDriver = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbUser = "root";
    String dbPass = "fo.......t";


    try{
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcDriver, dbUser, dbPass);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        //stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()){
        //rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        String userCertificate=rs.getString("certificate");
        UserSMSVerifier.messageGenarator(userCertificate, encryptedSMS);
        }



    }catch(Exception ex){out.print("Error 2: " +ex);}
    /*
    if(rs.next())
    {
        //session.setAttribute("userID", userID);
        out.print("Insert Succeed!");
        out.println();
        //out.print("Welcome!" + " " + session.getAttribute("userID"));
    }
    else
    {
        out.print("failed to login!");
        //session.invalidate();
    }
    */

%>
```

Comment: Can you show a stack trace? It would be helpful to know which line of code is generating the error.

Comment: see #3 codes (JSP).. the error collected by the "try{}catch(Exception ex){out.print("Error 2: " +ex);}" phrase..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your signature string contains 256 characters, however this is hexadecimal and really represents 128 *bytes*.

Before you verify the signature, you must convert it back to a byte array. This is not achieved through `someString.getBytes()` but rather via [`DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(someString)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseHexBinary%28java.lang.String%29) (or any other method you prefer from Google).

Also, I would strongly recommend you use the `Signature` class rather than the `Cipher` class when signing messages. Currently your code can only handle messages that are smaller than 128 bytes in length (smaller, in fact, due to padding). Instead, you should be hashing the message prior to signing (e.g. using the [`SHA256withRSA` mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Signature)).

Comment: typo **DatatypeConverter**  instead of **DatatypeConvert**. Save a minute for future reference

Answer (score 4):

As Duncan said, you need something like DateTypeConverter.

I used **Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedString)**, it returned 128 byte array.

When I had been using encodedString.getBytes(), it returned 172 byte array.

By the way I had 1024 bits RSA key.

Answer (score 2):

first convert text to Hex and then encrypt it, after encrypt you can convert from hex to string.

```
public static String toHex(String text)
{
    return String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, text.getBytes()));
}

public static byte[] hexToBytes(String hex)
{
    int l = hex.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[l/2];

    for (int i = 0; i < l; i += 2)
    {
        data[i/2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(hex.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(hex.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }

    return data;
}

public static String hexToStringA(String hex)
{
    return new String(hexToBytes(hex));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need split your data by the publicKey

```
int keyLength = publicKey.getModulus().bitLength() / 16;
String[] datas = splitString(data, keyLength - 11);
String mi = "";
        //如果明文长度大于模长-11则要分组加密
for (String s : datas) {
            mi += bcd2Str(cipher.doFinal(s.getBytes()));
}
return mi;


public static String bcd2Str(byte[] bytes) {
    char temp[] = new char[bytes.length * 2], val;

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        val = (char) (((bytes[i] & 0xf0) >> 4) & 0x0f);
        temp[i * 2] = (char) (val > 9 ? val + 'A' - 10 : val + '0');

        val = (char) (bytes[i] & 0x0f);
        temp[i * 2 + 1] = (char) (val > 9 ? val + 'A' - 10 : val + '0');
    }
    return new String(temp);
}
```

Comment: The answer by @Duncan is the correct solution. Just because you can do something does not mean you should.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code:

```
     EncDecProcessor ac = new EncDecProcessor();
     PublicKey publicKey = ac.getPublic(keyPath);
     this.cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
     byte[] b = new byte[2048];
     b = msg.getBytes("UTF-8");
     byte[] byteStr = Base64.decodeBase64(b);
     String Str = new String(cipher.doFinal(byteStr), "UTF-8");

     return Str;
```